# Removing span elements from a div element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have following code:

```
<div class="main-category">
    <span class="first-category"></span>
    <span class="last-category"></span>
</div>
```

Using JavaScript how do I remove both `span` elements inside the `div` element?

Comment: What about the contents of those `<span>`s? Should they be removed as well or remain intact?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @sirko yes I want both content and span tags to be deleted.

Comment: in that case, this should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll('.main-category span');`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all spans within a parent element of a specific class.

Then, iterate through the result and simply [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) each elements

```js
document.getElementById('remover').addEventListener('click', function()
{
  const elem = document.querySelectorAll('.main-category span');
  elem.forEach(e => e.remove());
});
```

```html
<div class = "main-category">
    outside of spans<br>
    <span class="first-category">foo</span>
    <span class="last-category">bar</span>
    outside of spans<br>
</div>

<div class = "main-category">
    outside of spans<br>
    <span class="first-category">hello</span>
    <span class="last-category">world</span>
    outside of spans<br>
</div>
<button type="button" id="remover">Remove elements</button>
```